# navbar not active when go to another route

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So i want to make my navbar post menu still active when i move from show posts route to the single post route.
this is the route: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/quia-laboriosam-nam-nostrum-porro
**this is the navbar code**

```
<li class="{{ set_active('posts') }}">
    <a href="{{ url('/posts')}}">Blog</a>
</li>
```

**this is the helper**

```
function set_active($route)
{
    if(is_array($route)){
        return in_array(Request::path(), $route) ? 'active-menu' : '';
    }
    return Request::path() == $route ? 'active-menu' : '';
}
```

how can i make the navbar menu stay active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below method to handle navbar active or inactive in laravel,

```
<li @if(Request::is('posts') || Request::is('singleposts')) class="active" @endif>
    <a href="{{ url('/posts')}}">Blog</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks bro it work. I change it like this. 
`<li @if(Request::is('posts') || Request::is('posts/*')) class="active-menu" @endif>`
      `<a href="{{ url('/posts')}}">Blog</a>`
`</li>`